# Call stack broken when waiting for console input?

Tags: visual-c++, console-application, visual-studio-debugging

I'm observing some interesting (and annoying) behavior on VS2010 (and VS2005):

Context: Running a 32bit Windows Console executable from the Visual Studio debugger on Win78 64bit.

When obtaining input from the console (via `std::getline`) and breaking into the debugger while the application waits for user input, the Visual Studio C++ debugger seems unable to resolve the call stack correctly. Sometimes, the call stack is completely broken, I can't even see main, and sometimes the callstack seems slightly off, that is, while my code is displayed correctly, it inserts some weird function call to the call stack.

Test-Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    using namespace std;
    cout << "Enter answer: ";
    std::string ans;
    std::getline(cin, ans); // << break into debugger while waiting here
    cout << "\nYou answered: \"" << ans << "\"\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Call Stack:

```
    kernel32.dll!_ReadConsoleInternal@32()  + 0x15 bytes    
    kernel32.dll!_ReadConsoleInternal@32()  + 0x15 bytes    
>   msvcr100d.dll!__dllonexit(int (void)* func=0x00000003, void (void)* * * pbegin=0x10113a60, void (void)* * * pend=0x00001000)  Line 272 + 0x5 bytes  C
    msvcr100d.dll!_read_nolock(int fh=0, void * inputbuf=0x10113a60, unsigned int cnt=4096)  Line 230 + 0x2e bytes  C
    msvcr100d.dll!_read(int fh=0, void * buf=0x10113a60, unsigned int cnt=4096)  Line 92 + 0x11 bytes   C
    msvcr100d.dll!_filbuf(_iobuf * str=0x1010f498)  Line 136 + 0x20 bytes   C
    msvcr100d.dll!fgetc(_iobuf * stream=0x1010f498)  Line 49 + 0x44 bytes   C
    msvcp100d.dll!std::_Fgetc<char>(char & _Byte=0, _iobuf * _File=0x1010f498)  Line 37 + 0xa bytes C++
    msvcp100d.dll!std::basic_filebuf<char,std::char_traits<char> >::uflow()  Line 435 + 0x13 bytes  C++
    msvcp100d.dll!std::basic_filebuf<char,std::char_traits<char> >::underflow()  Line 413 + 0xd bytes   C++
    msvcp100d.dll!std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits<char> >::sgetc()  Line 153 + 0x3f bytes    C++
    StdGetLine.exe!std::getline<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> > && _Istr={...}, std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & _Str="", const char _Delim='
')  Line 412 + 0x30 bytes   C++
    StdGetLine.exe!std::getline<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> >(std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char> > & _Istr={...}, std::basic_string<char,std::char_traits<char>,std::allocator<char> > & _Str="")  Line 483 + 0x38 bytes   C++
    StdGetLine.exe!main()  Line 9 + 0x10 bytes  C++
    StdGetLine.exe!__tmainCRTStartup()  Line 555 + 0x19 bytes   C
    StdGetLine.exe!mainCRTStartup()  Line 371   C
    kernel32.dll!@BaseThreadInitThunk@12()  + 0x12 bytes    
    ntdll.dll!___RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x27 bytes   
    ntdll.dll!__RtlUserThreadStart@8()  + 0x1b bytes
```

Note the bogus function `__dllonexit` on the call stack.

VS2010 also displays the message: *"The process appears to be deadlocked (or is not running any user-mode code). All threads have been stopped."*

Is this known behaviour? Do others have problems with callstacks where a thread reads from the console?

**What can I do to fix this?**

Note: While I don't mind the call stack that are slightly off overmuch, it happens in quite some percent of cases that **the callstack isn't usable at all and this also happens for some crash dumps** where I then can't see anymore where the call to `_ReadConsoleInternal` came from.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't really anything that needs fixing here.  You are buried deep inside Windows.  The debugger complains because your thread is blocked and not executing any code.  Windows itself is of course is optimized code, getting reliable stack traces out of optimized C or C++ code is notoriously difficult.  Setting up the Microsoft Symbol server so you get the PDBs for the Windows DLLs is important.  So is the Windows version, later builds of Windows no longer use the frame pointer omission optimization option, the one that make stack walks to difficult.

The debugger recovers well enough, everything at _read_nolock() and beyond is reliable.  Which is the only thing you should ever care about, it is not like you'd ever get to fix any bugs in Windows itself.  Using Debug + Break All just isn't that useful when you *know* what your program is going, surely you can find a better spot to put a breakpoint.

Comment: *Windows itself is of course is optimized code, getting reliable stack traces out of optimized C or C++ code is notoriously difficult* - I have seen my fair share of crash dumps over the last few years and `_ReadConsoleInternal` is actually the very first one where the MS symbols broke on me (for kernel32.dll) in a reproducible way, so I think it is really **not** appropriate to blame any optimizations for the broken call stacks -- after all that's what the PDB symbols are for.

Comment: *There isn't really anything that needs fixing here.* - Nuts! It's not a killer problem, but if I can't see anything in 50% of the cases, I dare say there could be something that warrants fixing.